# Grails ignore redirect and does not work

Tags: grails, redirect, http-status-code-302, grails-2.4

I use Grails 4.5. Redirects does not work at all. Here is simple example. I'm trying to redirect:

```
@Secured(['permitAll'])
class HomeController {

    def index() {
        println("index")
        render "index"
    }

    def one() {
        println("one")
        redirect(action: "index")
        println("two")
    }
}
```

When I GET: '//localhost:8080/***/home/one'. Grails ignore redirect. Output is:

```
one
two
```

If i replace *redirect* with **forward** it works as it has to be:

```
one
index
two
```

I use:

```
build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"
compile ":scaffolding:2.1.0"
compile ':cache:1.1.8'
runtime ":spring-security-core:2.0-RC4"
runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.5"
runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
runtime ":jquery:1.11.0.2"
runtime ":resources:1.2.14"
runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"
compile ":grails-melody:1.52.0"
compile ":barcode4j:0.3"

runtime ':twitter-bootstrap:3.3.1' // current: 3.3.1
compile ':fixtures:1.3'
compile ":webdriver:0.4.2"
```

Also spring-security's login/logout method does not work:

```
http://localhost:8080/***/login/index
http://localhost:8080/***/logout/index
```

But this works fine:

```
http://localhost:8080/***/j_spring_security_login
```

and redirects to:

```
http://localhost:8080/scangoods-api/login/auth
```

Comment: what headers do you get when requesting `/home/one`?

Comment: I dont get any exceptions.
Method one() works fine. Method index() doesn't calls at all.

Browser says that method GET was canceled: http://i.gyazo.com/af9710b6982e2a91235590d7d160560b.png

Comment: I mean http headers, from Developer Console or `curl -v`

Comment: oh, by canceled you mean no response at all? never saw this before I think :(

Comment: @AlekseyKozel, Hi, grails redirect is just a method call. you need to call redirect with "return" ie., **return redirect (action: 'index')**, then it will be redirected to index method and statement 'two' won't be printed. Hope this is what you are expecting.